# Fixing ActiveAdmin stylesheet issues

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4

I've set up activeadmin, but I had to pull the files out and put them into an assets/stylesheets and assets/javascripts subfolder called "admin", because the styles were inheriting into my main app and causing all sorts of issues.

I followed the instructions here: http://mrdanadams.com/2011/exclude-active-admin-js-css-rails
Where:

```
Create the folders app/assets/javascripts/admin and app/assets/stylesheets/admin and move the files active_admin.js and active_admin.css.scss into these folders, respectively.

In your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss you will find the following near the top:

 *= require_self
 *= require_true .

Change this to:

 *= require_self
 *= require_directory .

Do the same for application.js.

The culprit is active_admin’s asset_registration.rb and application.rb:

def register_default_assets
register_stylesheet 'active_admin.css'
register_javascript 'active_admin.js'
end

To clear these and replace them with the new files, add the following to the bottom of config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

config.clear_stylesheets!
config.register_stylesheet 'admin/active_admin.css'

config.clear_javascripts!
config.register_javascript 'admin/active_admin.js'
```

I've followed these instructions, but now my admin has lost styles/js functionality and it looks like my app is still trying to pull those files in.

Looking for help getting the assets to work, and keeping them out of my main app. Thank you!

Comment: I should add: this works fine locally. It's when I push to heroku that the styles seem to go missing.

Comment: Didn't they fix this issue with style interference lately?

Comment: They sure didn't @MichaelSzyndel . It's extremely frustrating. I am using the latest ver, too. I really would like to get it working properly.

Comment: Strange, I'm pretty sure I and this problem and then it was fixed with newer version (probably they stopped adding AA assets to pipeline)

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel - that is strange. I am using the newest version, all appropriate gems, and followed install instructions and I have one of the weirdest builds ever.